# DJI Mini 2 controller

Tags: usb, games, steam, gamepad, joystick

I'm trying to use my DJI Mini 2 controller in Ubuntu 22.04. I have the `joystick` and `jstest-gtk` packages installed. The system recognize the controller and creates two serial ports:

```
[11887.533124] usb 3-4.5: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[11887.637738] usb 3-4.5: New USB device found, idVendor=2ca3, idProduct=1020, bcdDevice= 4.04
[11887.637748] usb 3-4.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[11887.637751] usb 3-4.5: Product: C5
[11887.637754] usb 3-4.5: Manufacturer: DJI
[11887.637756] usb 3-4.5: SerialNumber: <myserial>
[11887.672706] cdc_acm 3-4.5:1.2: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[11887.672876] cdc_acm 3-4.5:1.4: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
[11887.672891] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[11887.672892] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters

$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 1ea7:002c SHARKOON Technologies GmbH USB Gaming Mouse
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 0a5c:2148 Broadcom Corp. BCM92046DG-CL1ROM Bluetooth 2.1 Adapter
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 0a5c:4503 Broadcom Corp. Mouse (Boot Interface Subclass)
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 0a5c:4502 Broadcom Corp. Keyboard (Boot Interface Subclass)
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 003 Device 015: ID 2ca3:0040 DJI Technology Co., Ltd.
```

But neither `jstest-gtk` nor Steam find an available controller.
Do I need to install some other packages?

Comment: It's quite likely these are not supported joystick devices. Do the devices show up under `/dev/input/js*`? What does `ls -l /dev/input/js*` show?

Comment: @popey there are no such devices under `/dev/input/` starting with js. But since the device is recognized, it's not just a matter of installing the right driver?